# Add mount options to a Deployment volume spec

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following `volume` definition in a `k8s` `Deployment` manifest

```
      volumes:
        - name: mypvc
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: "{{ .Values.disk.name }}"
            fsType: "{{ .Values.disk.fsType }}"
```

Is it possible/allowed to add some mount options, as in

```
      volumes:
        - name: mypvc
          gcePersistentDisk:
            pdName: "{{ .Values.disk.name }}"
            fsType: "{{ .Values.disk.fsType }}"
            mountOptions:
              - rsize=10240
              - wsize=10240
              - timeout=600
              - retry=5
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource v1` currently allow only 4 configuration parameters.

```
fsType - ext4 | xfs | ntfs

partition - 0 | 1 ....

pdName - [GCE PD Name)

readOnly - true | false
```

Comment: Just came across [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/_print/#mount-options) one; doesn't this imply that `mountOptions` is allowed?

Comment: You can mount volumes from different optional disk types. You can see in that link `GCEPersistentDisk` which you are already using.